# What Does Enabling Symfony Annotations Actually Do?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

The [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) say to enable annotations you should run the following command.

```
$ composer require annotations
```

What is actually going on behind the scenes with this command to enable annotations?

It's confusing to me because normally I'd use something like

```
composer require foo/baz
```

To install the `foo/baz` package -- but `annotations` isn't a package -- or at least it doesn't look like one to me. Packages normally have a `namespace/packagename` structure and `annotations` is a single word.

Additionally, I diffed my composer.json file before and after running this command and the onyl different apepars to be bumping the minor version number on `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` -- (which shouldn't even matter since `^5.1` SemVer translates to 5.latestst -- right?)

```
$ diff composer.json composer.json.orig 
8c8
<         "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
---
>         "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
```

So how does this `composer require annotations` actually work, and what changes is it making that enable route annotations?

Comment: It is called `Symfony Flex`. Read more https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html#how-does-flex-work and recipe for `annotations` located here https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/5.2/manifest.json

Comment: Thanks @VadimAshikhman -- happy to mark that as an accepted answer if it's an actual answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"annotations" here is an **alias** to a **Symfony Recipe**.

Go to the Symfony recipes website : https://flex.symfony.com/ and search for 'annotations'. You will likely find two packages, and the one that is of interest to you is the second one : **sensio/framework-extra-bundle**

When your run `composer require annotations`, composer installs the package (exactly like if you did `composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle`, or updates it if you already have it), and it **also runs the recipe associated to it** (*depending on your version, it's here : [https://github.com/symfony/recipes/tree/master/sensio/framework-extra-bundle](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/tree/master/sensio/framework-extra-bundle_)*)

What the recipe does is in fact copy a bunch of files to your working directory, so that the configuration is done automatically and you don't have to bother. Some recipes add a new console command, add config files, or a binary ... it's quite powerful.

All these changes are written to the *relatively* new `symfony.lock` config file, where you can find the recipes that have been run with some info.

> NB : you should commit the `symfony.lock` file if you use a VCS